# CADisplayLink behaves similar to NSTimer, framerate bug

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-animation, nstimer, cadisplaylink

I have implemented CADisplayLink, but yet it behaves similar to NSTimer in that when there are a lot of draws it locks the fps to 40 and never gets out of there, even if there are a lot fewer draws afterward.  This happens on the itouch 3 and itouch 4. I'm using openGL to render, and openAL for sounds. What's going on. Help Please!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by profiling the app. I wouldn't suspect CADisplayLink weirdness till it's demonstrated that the app should in fact be running faster than it is.